# Call the notify_all method after store with release memory order on an atomic

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic, c++20, stdatomic

I have the following code being executed on a single thread (written in C++20):

```cpp
std::atomic_bool is_ready{};

void SetReady() {
  is_ready.store(true, std::memory_order_release);
  is_ready.notify_all();
}
```

Other threads execute the text listed below:

```cpp
void Wait() {
  is_ready.wait(false, std::memory_order_acquire);
}
```

As I know, release memory order doesn't ensure that the operations located after it will not be reordered by a compiler. So, can I place `notify_all()` after `store()` with release memory order? Is it safe? Just I have some thoughts that `store()` may be sequenced before `notify_all()` and hence may not be reordered.

Comment: A good rule of thumb is that in a single specific thread, operations on a single specific atomic are not reordered relative to one another. They can only be reordered relative to accesses to other objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The memory orders are irrelevant here. They only affect ordering of memory access *other* than on the atomic itself and you have none.

The compiler cannot reorder the `notify_all` call before the store in any case, because [`notify_all` is specified](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/atomics.types.operations#34) to wake up all waiting operations on the atomic which are [*eligible to be unblocked*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/atomics.wait#4).

Which these are depends on whether, in the [global modification order](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order#Modification_order) of the atomic, the last store which [*happens-before*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order#Happens-before) the call to `notify_all` is ordered after the store observed by the waiting thread when it blocked.

In your shown code the `true` store is [*sequenced-before*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) the `notify_all` call (in the same thread), which implies that the store *happens-before* the call, but if the lines were switched, then that wouldn't be the case anymore.

Moving the `notify_all` before the store would thus potentially change the set of waiting operations which are *eligible to be unblocked*.

If the compiler was allowed to do that, then the waiting/notification mechanism would be pretty useless. This is also the same as for other operations on the same atomic in the same thread (or really any operations on the same storage location in the same thread). The compiler cannot reorder these either.

So yes, it is safe and the `Wait` thread will not wait forever. (I am assuming that the initialization `std::atomic_bool is_ready{};` is happening before either of the shown thread functions start execution.)